# Formatting specific found words within a text string in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, string-formatting, text-parsing

I have a list of words that I am searching through a "Notes" field within a table, that when I display that Notes field in my Crystal Report, I would like to somehow highlight (change font color) for only the specific flagged word within the note text string.

Example:
word list: Joe, Sarah, Amy, Jeff
note text: "I stopped by and talked with Joe to check on the account status, and Amy said hello."

desired result: Note text displays in the report with the words "Joe" and "Amy" in red.

I've tried using RTF and HTML in the Text Interpretation parameter within the properties, where I can successfully format the note text to either of these text outputs. However, I still don't know the right code to isolate and format the specific words from my list, especially if more than one of my words shows up within the field text.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar a couple of years ago:

```
StringVar SearchText := "has";
StringVar Htm1 := "<b>";
StringVar Htm2 := "</b>";
StringVar Result := ""; 
StringVar Temp := ""; 
NumberVar Start := 1;  
NumberVar Ln := Len(SearchText);  
NumberVar Loc := Instr({@TextField}, SearchText);  
While Loc > 0 Do (  
    Temp := Mid({@TextField}, Start, Loc - Start) + Htm1 + Mid({@TextField}, Loc, Ln) & Htm2;
    Result := Result + Temp;  
    Start := Loc + Ln;  
    Loc := Instr(Start, {@TextField}, SearchText);  
);  
Temp := Mid({@TextField}, Start);  
Result := Result + Temp;  
Result
```

In this case I am searching the field called @TextField for the value in SearchText and am bolding the values.  Probably not the most efficient code, but it works.

Comment: This is brilliant (to me!), works perfectly! I think I can take this code now and make it work for my whole list of words.

Thank you so much for responding!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but i found it searching for an issue i had.  The answered code works, but seemed a bit cluttered for me, and also i needed to be able to provide a list of words to highlight.  Here is what i came up with.

```
Local Stringvar Array searchwords:=MakeArray("Joe", "Sarah", "Amy");
local stringvar notes:={Notes};
local numbervar i;
for i:=1 to count(searchwords) do (
    notes:=replace(notes,searchwords[i],"<font color='red'>" & searchwords[i] & "</font>",1,-1,1);
);
notes
```

The only thing to note, is that this will find results when the search word is part of a larger word - i.e. "WORK" would be BOLDED in "Workshop".

While this works for our needs as we want "working","work","worked" etc. to all highlight, crystal reports not supporting Regex is quite a large downside.

Comment: Looks a lot easier to work with... Is your solution case sensitive?

Comment: This code uses the Crystal Function "Replace" which can be made to do either case sensitive, or insensitive using the final argument. Please reference http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic649.html

Comment: One thing to note, that because it searches the entire string one word at a time, if you insert a word, that is also later in the searchwords, it will have most likely unwanted affects.

i.e.  In the example where we are saerching for names, lets say one of the names we wanted was "Red"(boys name), that would then replace the 'red' the color notation from the font tags.  Obviously there are ways around this issue by using hex code instead of color names, but it is worth noting to be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for your link and explanation. So 1, -1, 1 means the comparison is case insensitive, but the replacement string will be the literal string in the array? So, if the Notes field has the word "JOE", the formula will replace it with <font color='red'>Joe</font> making the upper into proper case?